# Fix Me Please - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

You put me up, They tear me down
Some may laugh like I was a clown.
Fix me up and put me back,
Perhaps now we're more on track.

Crazy and impossible things,
All sorts of silly strings.
The answer is often clear,
Why my reputation do you smear?

Think about it, puzzle it out,
What this riddle is all about.
Maybe not the way you think,
What am I? Don't let hopes sink.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems a bit too obvious to be correct to me, but I'm going to say you're a:

> closed puzzle/riddle on Puzzling.SE, probably with the catch-all "lateral thinking" tag people put on just about anything.

You put me up, They tear me down
Some may laugh like I was a clown.

> You got posted and quickly closed, most likely for being "too broad". Laughter is still common in these cases, because the premise of these puzzles is often ridicilous.

Fix me up and put me back,
Perhaps now we're more on track.

> You'd like to be edited and reopened. Then you'll be "on track" to get answers.

Crazy and impossible things,
All sorts of silly strings.

> I'm not sure this needs much explanation. Have you seen some of the posts here? Infinite rope, prisoners that all have perfect logic/memory...

The answer is often clear,
Why my reputation do you smear?

> The OP almost *always* thinks his own question is clear, no matter if it is or not, so get offended (smeared) by the downvotes that often accompany votes to close.

Think about it, puzzle it out,
What this riddle is all about.

> I already did that. I think.

Maybe not the way you think,
What am I? Don't let hopes sink.

> "Not the way you think" is almost literally "lateral thinking". Please don't let the hopes of having a well received post die...

Comment: Very very close. Go a little more specific.

Comment: More specific than the last spoilered part?

Comment: More specific than the overall answer. I like the last spoilered part.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure exactly how much more specific I can get without just changing it *to* that part, if that's not the intended answer.

Comment: Without coming right out and saying it, you may have gotten the exact answer in part of your answer. I'm hoping you can change the whole answer to that and explain how the lines best fit the more specific answer.

Comment: The answer might be referring to a "lateral thinking" post because they are mainly closed from being too broad (and down voted), People always make silly/impossible incorrect answers with them, but then they eventually get fixed by the OP to become more specific (If they aren't removed).

Comment: @MarkN Nicely timed edit and comment :P

Comment: @Geobits Very nice. And nice input from MarkN as well.

Comment: @AggieKidd I had once felt its wrath....one does not easily forget such things..

Answer (score 6):

I think you are

> dreams or aspirations

You put me up, They tear me down
Some may laugh like I was a clown.

> Someone ruins your dreams by saying it is silly or impossible.

Fix me up and put me back,
Perhaps now we're more on track.

> Follow your dreams, even if people think it is silly.

Crazy and impossible things,
All sorts of silly strings.

> Dreams can be strange or silly.

The answer is often clear,
Why my reputation do you smear?

> Other people sometimes say, "Stop dreaming, silly!"

Maybe not the way you think,
What am I? Don't let hopes sink.

> Don't give up at achieving your dreams, even if it doesn't work out.

Comment: +1 Very nice. You make me seem like a inspiring person. Not what I was going for though. The last two lines hold clues that will be needed.

Answer (score 4):

I was thinking you're a

> piñata

You put me up, They tear me down

> That's what you do with piñatas

Some may laugh like I was a clown.

> Piñatas are often funny shapes.

Fix me up and put me back,
Perhaps now we're more on track.

> I don't think people usually do this, but hey, why not? Usually the kid just barely breaks it enough to get the candy to fall out.

Crazy and impossible things,
All sorts of silly strings.

> [Silly String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silly_String) is exactly the kind of prize that would be in there.

The answer is often clear,
Why my reputation do you smear?

> I don't know about this line.

Think about it, puzzle it out,
What this riddle is all about.
Maybe not the way you think,
What am I? Don't let hopes sink.

> I just figured that this line was a fun closing verse. I'm new to Puzzling.SE, so I didn't know that every single line has to have significance.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE. Nice first attempt. Generally with riddles all of the lines will fit the answer somehow.